# Setting up distributed caching in node

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, distributed-caching

I have an application, in which I have to fetch a list of users. The API to fetch the list requires an authentication token, which expires every 1 hour. So, in order to fetch the users, I first need to make a token call and post that I need to make the fetch call. How can I cache the token which is valid for 1 hour in Node? We have multiple pods, so I need a distributed cache to make sure that the token value is the same across the pods. Will it be possible to implement it in `node` and how to implement it? Any kind of resources/tutorials would be really helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is Node.js the client that needs credentials to access some other service, after obtaining a token? Why would all processes need to have the same token - can't they all have their own separate tokens that are all valid at the same time?

Comment: @RobertKawecki Actually we are hitting some third-party service that provides a token that could be used to access their APIs. The token expires every 1 hour. So, to save token call and post that API calls every time, I was thinking of storing the token in the node which would save token call from every client.

Answer (score 0):

So you're calling an external service, but you need a valid token that you have to obtain first.

Take a look at how existing software tackles it. For example, Microsoft's Graph API SDK (which also uses bearer token auth):
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/CustomAuthenticationProvider.md

You inject an "authentication provider" that authenticates and retrieves a token from the remote service when necessary. Next, when you need to make a call to the API, the client checks if it has a token in-memory. If it doesn't (or if it's expired), it asks the authentication provider for a new token. So, the in-memory cache layer is in the client object.

Another approach is in-memory caching, but in the Authentication Provider layer - then, the client can blindly ask it for a token every time, and let the Provider decide whether to use the current token or ask for a new one.

I would refrain from putting the token on a network-accessible cache - it opens up a potential security hole for leaking the token, and does not seem to serve any purpose.